# How to find the value of a dynamic key in javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object

```
var obj = {a:{b:'value'}};
```

where key 'a' is dynamic, key 'b' is constant, so I am not able to get value from obj['a'].

Is there any way to get the value of key 'b' without knowing key 'a'.

Comment: If the key is always the first (and, perhaps, the only one) in the object, you can do: `obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].b;` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys . Alternatively, you can search for the `b` key: `obj[Object.keys(obj).find(i => obj[i].b !== null && obj[i].b !== undefined)].b`. Beware that in this second method you should also check the the find result is not null or undefined, otherwise you will have a nullreference error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of an object with an unknown single key in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208902/get-the-value-of-an-object-with-an-unknown-single-key-in-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all the keys of object using `Object.keys(<obj>)`

In your case:

```
key = Object.keys(obj)[0]; // will return "a"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var obj = {a:{b:'value'}};
obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.values`, like so:

```
const obj = { a: { b:'value' } };
Object.values(obj)[0].b // 'value'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
res = { data: { list: { names: { blk: { cnt: 10 } } } }, test:'test' };
let val = getObjectVal(res, 'cnt')

getObjectVal(data, findKey){
let result = '';
for (let key in data) {
  if (key == findKey)
    result = data[findKey];
  if ((typeof data[key] === "object") && (data[key] !== null)) {
    if (key != findKey)
      result = getObjectVal(data[key], findKey)
  }
}
return result ? result : '';}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of b

```js
var obj = {a:{b:'value'}};
console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {a:{b:'value'}};
// Looking for each object variables in obj
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
  // Looking for each object variables in the obj[key]
 Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(function(key2){
 // do what you want if key_2 is b
  if(key2=='b')
    console.log(obj[key][key2])
 })
})
```