# Display value by index with Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got an array of objects:

I'm trying to display 225000 , I must not use 'january', but an index (month number).

So I'm trying :

```js
var myArray = [{
    'january_data': 195000
  },
  {
    'february_data': 225000
  } // And the list goes on for each months of the year
]


console.log(myArray[1])
```

And it is not working ... 
Any idea ?

**Explanation :**
I musnt use the 'january_data' STRING, my js query changes all the time with current month, i'm using numbers as INDEX, that is why i'm using  console.log(myArray[1])

Comment: What do you mean "it's not working"? Provided the array is fixed by inserting the missing comma, logging `myArray[1]` will log `{'february_data':225000}` Is you actual question how to get 225000 from `{'february_data':225000}`?

Comment: Do you control the structure of the data? If the data always has twelve elements, then get rid of the keys and use a simple array. [195000,22500,...]. The access arrayName[0]. If you want to use the month number, then do this: [null, 195000,22500,...] and now arrayName[1] will provide Januararys data.

Comment: Thank you Randy, yes it is always 12 months length ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the value of an object with an unknown single key in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208902/get-the-value-of-an-object-with-an-unknown-single-key-in-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Object.values or Object.keys:

```js
var myArray = [{
    'january_data': 195000
  },
  {
    'february_data': 225000
  }
];

var obj = myArray[1]; // [1] for February
console.log(Object.values(obj)[0]);    // note the [0] for the first value
console.log(obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]); // note the [0] for the first key
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Object.values and pass in the object you get from the index to just get the value. If you just use the index, you will get the whole object with key and value.

```js
var myArray = [{
    'january_data': 195000
  },
  {
    'february_data': 225000
  }
]

console.log("Array",Object.values(myArray[1]))
console.log("String", Object.values(myArray[1]).toString())
```

Comment: Thank you ! Im trying this now !

Comment: You should add `[0]` so the result is `225000` (not `[ 225000 ]`)

Answer (score -3):

This is an array of Objects, Try:

```
console.log(myArray[1].february_data);
```

Comment: OP has stated repeatedly they need to extract the number without knowing the name of the key.