# How to fix the "Type Error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map

I am trying to perform a fetch call to return an array however, when i try to use a map function to iterate the array the compiler gives an error saying that cannot read property map of undefined which i'm stuck and i also did some research on similar problems but to no avail. I am new in React here therefore i'm not sure which part causes the error. I realise that it comes from my setState function call.

This is my App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
 constructor()  {
     super();
     this.state={
        currencies: [],
        };



        }


handleChange =(event) => {

   let initialData = [];
        const url = `http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=ea263e28e82bbd478f20f7e2ef2b309f&symbols=${event.target.value}&format=1`

console.log("the url is: " + url)
 fetch(url).
  then(data =>{ return data.json();})
  .then(findData => {
   initialData = findData.rates
   console.log(initialData)
   this.setState({

        currencies: initialData.rates,

        });
});

}

  render() {
    const{currencies} = this.state; 
    return (
      <div className="App">
    { this.state.currencies.map((current) => <div> {current.rates}</div>)}  


        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
     <h1 className="App-title"> Welcome to DKK website </h1>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <select id="select1" name ="currency" value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="EUR">-- Selecting: NILL --</option>
                <option value="CAD">-- Selecting: CAD --</option>
                <option value="SGD">-- Selecting: SGD --</option>
                <option value="AFN">-- Selecting: AFN --</option>
        </select>


        </div>


<button className="pressMe" > Set Button </button>
<br/>
<br/>


     <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: can you `console.log( this.state.currencies)`? it is most likely not an array.

Comment: yes it outputs [index,value]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API call returns a promise base json data, which means there's no array to map over immediately use `Object.keys` form extracting keys for object for Array.map function. check blow code, also some issues fixed in this code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loader: false,
    currencies: []
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    const val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      selectValue: val
    });
  };

  fetchData = () => {
    this.setState({
      loader: true
    });
    let initialData = [];
    const url = `http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=ea263e28e82bbd478f20f7e2ef2b309f&symbols=${
      this.state.selectValue
    }&format=1`;

    console.log("the url is: " + url);
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(findData => {
        initialData = findData.rates;
        this.setState({
          currencies: initialData,
          loader: false
        });
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    const { currencies, loader } = this.state;
    let list = null;
    if (loader) {
      list = "loading...";
    } else if (!loader && currencies) {
      list = Object.keys(currencies).map(current => (
        <div key={current}>
          {current}: {currencies[current]}
        </div>
      ));
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <h1 className="App-title"> Welcome to DKK website </h1>
          {list}
          <div className="dropdown">
            <select
              id="select1"
              name="currency"
              value={this.state.selectValue}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              <option value="EUR">-- Selecting: NILL --</option>
              <option value="CAD">-- Selecting: CAD --</option>
              <option value="SGD">-- Selecting: SGD --</option>
              <option value="AFN">-- Selecting: AFN --</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          <button className="pressMe" onClick={this.fetchData}>
            Set Button
          </button>
          <br />
          <br />

          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi are u able to display the map data on button click instead current implementation?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and patience

Comment: @XingChen please check latest code, data fetch on button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Your API call returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which means there's no array to `map` over immediately. Use [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to wait for the API call to complete. Once the data comes back from the API you can save it to state.

This code sample renders the results. When the currency selection changes, an API call is made. Async/Await handles the promise and saves the results to state. React "reacts" by rendering the results as soon as the state changes.

The API returns a different `rates` object for every currency. Because those results are unpredictable, [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is used to access the name and value of the unknown response object. See [more on Object.keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208902/).

You use destructuring to access `this.state.currencies`, so you can simply refer to it as `currencies` in the remainder of your component. Finally, because you attached the `handleChange` event to your `select` tag, the button isn't needed.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currencies: []
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.getData(event.target.value);
  };

  async getData(target) {
    const url = `http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=ea263e28e82bbd478f20f7e2ef2b309f&symbols=${target}&format=1`;

    console.log("the url is: " + url);
    let data = await fetch(url).then(data => {
      return data.json();
    });
    this.setState({ currencies: data });
  }

  render() {
    const { currencies } = this.state;
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <h1 className="App-title"> Welcome to DKK website </h1>

          <div class="dropdown">
            <select
              id="select1"
              name="currency"
              value={this.state.selectValue}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              <option value="EUR">-- Selecting: NILL --</option>
              <option value="CAD">-- Selecting: CAD --</option>
              <option value="SGD">-- Selecting: SGD --</option>
              <option value="AFN">-- Selecting: AFN --</option>
            </select>
          </div>

          {/* <button className="pressMe"> Set Button </button> */}
          <br />

          <ul>
            <li>Base: {currencies.base}</li>
            <li>Date: {currencies.date}</li>
            <li>Timestamp: {currencies.timestamp}</li>
            {/* Sometimes currencies.rates is undefined.
            Use conditional rendering to prevent errors when there is no value */}
            {currencies.rates && (
              <li>
                Rate for {Object.keys(currencies.rates)}:{" "}
                {Object.values(currencies.rates)}
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>

          {/*
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
           */}
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Awesome Charlie! it works! however, how do i display the current.rates upon a button click to a label?

Comment: And one question: what does Asyn do?

Comment: All you have to do to display the data is 1) save the retrieved data to state, 2) map over this.state.currencies, rendering some ui. If you'd like me to post a sample, I'm happy to do that.

Comment: yes please could u post a sample for me to reference on as this is my first app on react! i'm thrilled!!

Comment: Does this line  {this.state.currencies.map(current => (
          <div> {current.rates}</div>
        ))} allow me to display current.rates? because it doesn't display

Comment: I edited my original response to include displaying the current rates.